# Could we have some more visual difference between visited and unvisited links?

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

I read the questions on UX in "newest" sort order. Usually I'll scroll down to the first question I have already read before working my way back up to the latest and greatest.

On StackOverflow this is greatly aided by the difference in style for visited and unvisited title links. The questions I have already read stand out by the color of their titles. So I only need a cursory glance to know where to start working my way up again.

StackOverflow also uses blue for its question titles, as does Programmers. The difference on Programmers is already markedly less than on StackOverflow, but still much better than here at UX.

Could we please have some more visual distinction between visited and unvisited question title links?

Comment: as an aside ... I just asked about this over on the main site: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/45414/how-to-mark-visited-vs-non-visited-links

Comment: @ColinSharpe: yes, spotted that one when you asked it. Didn't have anything to add to Michael's answer :-) Interesting privacy issue you found trying to use background images.